# JS Promise: Return mapped data

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I have a function "mapTranslations" which gets data from a server and then maps it. At the moment I use a callback to return the data. I wan't to use promises though - I don't have a approach on how I could return the mapped data and not the data from the "somePromiseReturningFunction".

```js
function mapTranslations(callback){
    somePromiseReturningFunction(...).then(function (languageData) {
        var translations = {};
        languageData.d.results.forEach(function (obj) {
            translations[obj.key] = obj[browserLang];
        });
        callback(translations);
    });
}
```

Using it like this:

```js
mapTranslations(function(translations){
    console.log(translations);
});
```

Goal:

```js
mapTranslations().then(function(translations){
    console.log(translations) //Example, wouldn't be an anonymous function
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you return the original promise and return a value from your `.then()` handler like this (more explanation below):

```
function mapTranslations(){
    return somePromiseReturningFunction(...).then(function (languageData) {
        var translations = {};
        languageData.d.results.forEach(function (obj) {
            translations[obj.key] = obj[browserLang];
        });
        return translations;
    });
}

// usage
mapTranslations().then(function(results) {
     // access results here
}).catch(function(err) {
     // handle error here
});
```

When you return a value from a `.then()` handler that becomes the resolved value of the returned promise and the caller will see that value.  Thus you can modify the returned value from the original promise and return it in your own `.then()` handler.

In addition, you really don't want to ever wrap a promise in a callback.  That just throws away all the advantages of promises (ability to chain, automatic async error propagation, ability to manage/coordinate multiple async operations, interoperability with other async operations, etc...).  Instead, just return the promise and let the caller use `.then()` on the returned promise to get access to the data or errors.  FYI, in your proposed callback code, you were silently eating any errors from `somePromiseReturningFunction()`.  If it rejected the promise it returns, you had no handler so the caller would never know.  If you just return the promise from your function, that error handling comes for free.

---

FYI, you may want to use `.reduce()` instead of `.forEach()` as it aligns a little better with what you're doing:

```
function mapTranslations(){
    return somePromiseReturningFunction(...).then(function (languageData) {
        return languageData.d.results.reduce(function(translations, obj) {
            translations[obj.key] = obj[browserLang];
            return translations;
        }, {});
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's just what I was looking for. I didn't now you can return it like this. Of course wrapping promises in callbacks isn't the way to go - that's why I wrote this question. :)

Comment: @Sandrooco - I added a new suggestion to shorten your code with `.reduce()` instead of `.forEach()`.

Comment: Looks good - why is translations undefined in the second iteration?

Comment: @Sandrooco - I was missing a `return` statement in the second iteration.  I fixed that.

Comment: Nice that works! Just for my comprehension: I return the translations object for the next iterations?

Comment: @Sandrooco - Yes, the job of the `.reduce()` callback is to take the value passed in as the first argument, modify it and return it for the next iteration.  The value returned from the last iteration is the value returned from the `.reduce()` call.  You can see the description [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do, the `then` can return a value and it returns a new promise you can use.

```
function mapTranslations(){

    return somePromiseReturningFunction(...).then(function (languageData) {
        var translations = {};
        languageData.d.results.forEach(function (obj) {
            translations[obj.key] = obj[browserLang];
        });
        return translations;
    });

}

mapTranslations().then( .... ).catch( ... );
```